# How do I display self-hosted video content

Tags: 7, files

What I am trying to do is embed a self-hosted video on a webpage. I have the video uploaded onto the web hosting in mp4, ogv and webm formats; converted where necessary using Miro Video Converter (if that helps?).

The code I have in place on the webpage is:

```
<center><video width="90%" controls>
<source src="/system/files/HBA_ONLINE.mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="/system/files/HBA_ONLINE.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="/system/files/HBA_ONLINE.ogv" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support this video tag - Try viewing directly <a href="/system/files/HBA_ONLINE.mp4.mp4"> here </a></video></center>
```

The only format that seems to work is mp4 on Google Chrome; other browsers simply won't play the video in any format.

The silly question is; do I need to use a dedicated Drupal 7 module???

Comment: If you inspect in dev console of browser, what happens when you right click on these src links and opt to open in new tab? Do your paths resolve?

Comment: Thanks @J.Reynolds - you made me look again at the dev console and fond the problem with the 403 errors!

Answer (score 0):

A learning process for anyone who makes the same mistake.

I found that the files had be uploaded with role based content access as part of our file repository. That meant anonymous users would get a 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

There's the [video](https://www.drupal.org/project/video) module you could optionally join with the [media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) system. this bridge module (Media Video) still is [sandobx](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/dlumberg/1364538).

> This will provide you a field display of the video in HTML5 with flash
>   fallback for the large majority of da browser's.